# Extracting parts into components error: Unexpected token, expected "..."

Tags: reactjs, components

I am getting that error when extracting part of my code to a separate coponent.
I can't find where the problem is coming from.

[image]
What does it mean?

> Unexpected token, expected "..."

Whole code:

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-bash-rixig?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Person` component takes `person` as a prop. In the error message, it shows you're incorrectly assigning props to the `Person` component. It should be this:

```
// App.js - starting at line 79
<ul>
  {persons.map((person) => (
    <Person key={person.id} person={person} />
  ))}
</ul>
```

If the `Person` component was like this:

```
// Person.js
import React from "react";

const Person = ({ name, number }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      {name} {number}
    </li>
  );
};

export default Person;
```

you could pass the `name` and `number` props to the `Person` component like so:

```
// App.js
<ul>
  {persons.map((person) => (
    <Person key={person.id} {...person} />
  ))}
</ul>

// which is equivalent to
<ul>
  {persons.map((person) => (
    <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} number={person.number} />
  ))}
</ul>
```

This is a common pattern to spread (...) the props. In this case, it means you're passing all the properties of a person into the Person component.